# Prove that the following polynomial has at least one zero in the interval $(0,1)$ by using Rolle's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Suppose that:

$$\frac{a_0}{n+1}+\frac{a_1}{n}+\cdots+a_n=0$$

Prove that the polynomial:
$a_ox^{n}+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n$

has at least one zero in the interval $(0,1)$ using Rolle's theorem.

Comment: What is $\int_0^1\,\left(a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n\right)\,\text{d}x$?

Comment: Hint: Note that if $P$ is your polynomial, we have $\int_0^1P(t)dt=0$. So $P$ cannot be ($>0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$) or ($<0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$)

Comment: Hint: consider the polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{a_{n-i}x^{n-i+1}}{n-i +1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = a_0 \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + a_1 \frac{x^{n}}{n} + \cdots + a_nx.$

Now we have $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, apply Rolle's theorem.